# How can I install Jenkins on Azure?

Tags: jenkins, azure

Currently I have Jenkins installed on Windows Server as a Service but I am looking at installing Jenkins on Azure but the MSDN docs talk about creating a Jenkins server on an Azure Linux VM from the Azure portal, outlined in the following link:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/jenkins/install-jenkins-solution-template.

Is this the only way or can I install it on a Windows VM and run it as if it was installed on a local Windows machine ?
Thanks

Comment: Jenkins is a free software and can be installed under Windows; please be specific what do you imply with "as if it was installed on local machine", that is running in the cloud is not exactly same as locally. But generally it should be possible, yes.

Comment: At the moment  I  have Jenkins installed on a local Windows machine and the build scripts access project that get pushed down from source control on the c:\ drive and compiled using MSBuild.
So what your saying is that I can spin up a VM with Windows in the cloud and install Jenkins on it and perform the pull from source control and build the projects. So it is a Windows machine except its on the Cloud ?

Comment: Yes to some extent, with the limitation it's a VM run under some hypervisor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then yes, you can create a windows VM in azure and install jenkins on it the same way as on a local machine.

They're might be some differences in the configuration of the environment for example about security, user access, routing etc

Answer (score 0):

Do you really care about the OS behind jenkins that much?  Jenkins is fine running in a Docker container in your choice of orchestration environments (Kubernetes, Dokku, etc.).

Running jobs on the controller is not a great idea, so the OS for build jobs is going to depend on the agents.  Running agents in containers gives you a lot of flexibility, including having different pools of agents for different OS versions.